# Advantages of Javascript over InspectElement Issues?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee

Can we hide code which is available through InspectElement to End User?
We are very new and  developing a new Product based on javascript and java technologies. Almost 70% completed the prod. We have done so much issues(Calculations) in forms based on javascript.
Problem is the end user can easily modify those calculations and it leads to wrong info sit in database. we are not able to write serverside validations for all those forms(70).

Comment: Never trust the user's input. Either validate serverside or do the calculation itself completely serverside.

Comment: You learn next time not to rely on client-side script for logic which should be on the server-side.

Comment: thanks Blender and Parnell

Comment: any other ideas please ...